# Gradle sync in Android Studio showed an error 'Could not GET kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.50.pom'. with status code 403 from server

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I created a new Android project by importing one of our company projects today. I am not an Android programmer but I had to run it and measure performance. So I installed Android Studio today on my Ubuntu 18.04 box. I also update plugins.

During the first Gradle sync, there was an error:

```
Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.50/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.50.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

The build.gradle file looks like the following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com" }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com" }
        google()
    }
}
```

With my Chrome,
I cannot access 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.50/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.50.pom'
but I can download pom file with `https` with by browser.

So I tried to change `http` to `https` in the above `build.gradle` but got the following errors:

```
Repository not found.
Process command 'git' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I searched and tried the following:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I also tried to add some url in `maven{ url ... }` but got the same error (`Repository not found.`)

Please help me how to successfully finish gradle sync.

Thank you!

Comment: Just one more info about my problem. I also suspected that this issue might be related to `git`. However, I have no problem with `git clone` with `https` so far.... :-<

Comment: I thouhght that maybe some setting of my desktop caused this problem.. so I installed Ubuntu 18.04 into another laptop, installed Android Studio and ran Gradle Sync. But I got the same error again. :-<

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer to my question.

I found that there are some proxy setting in gradle.property file and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use proxy
you can go to File>settings and search HTTP proxy and select Manual proxy configuration and Http
now you will be set Host name and Port number:::

```
Host : mirror.vtwo.org , mirror1.vtwo.org --> Port : 8850
Proxy Server : fodev.org --> Proxy Port : 8118
Proxy Server : mirror.mbaas.ir --> Proxy Port : 8700
Proxy Server : android.hive.ir --> Proxy Port : 8080
```